# How to make 2 monitor screenshots fit?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screenshot

I have 2 monitors, each running @1080p. When I make a screenshot, the two monitors just doesn't fit in the image. Example:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Awe.png) The physical size of the two monitors are not the same but because the pixel number is the same I think that it just a setting question. So, my question is: how can I make it default to show the two monitors screen the same size in screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the monitors are offset vertically.

In Display Settings, drag them into alignment and click apply - they should snap into place.

If you have purposefully offset them because of their physical positioning, then you can either have a perfect screenshot, or correctly aligned displays, but not both.

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]